# Insercion Multimple con C# y MySQL

Tags: c#

Quiero realizar la insercion a mi base de datos en una tabla mas de 70000 registros que obtengo de un archivo s3db , segun si hace la insercion pero solo de 50 registros y luego arroja como un tipo de error que anexo
"Error: al Concectarse a la Base de datos. Error connecting: Timeout experid, the timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. this many have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached"

este es mi codigo para insertar a la base de datos de mysql:
Seccion del Boton de Examinar y buscar el archivo s3db:

//Sirvara para obtener el tipo de base de datos a cargar

```
private void gBtnExaminar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        OpenFileDialog fBrowDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

        string path = fBrowDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK ? fBrowDialog.FileName : "";
        gTxtDitectorio.Text = path;
        cnx = new ConexionSQLite();
        try
        {
            cnx.GetConnection(path);
            string sql = "select ID_PROGRAMA,NOMBRE,PRIMER_APELLIDO,SEGUNDO_APELLIDO,CURP,TELEFONO,EMAIL,GRADO_ESCOLAR,REGION_ID,SEDE,CVE_CCT,NOMBRE_CCT,CCT,MUNICIPIO_ID,CVE_LOCALIDAD,LOCALIDAD_ID,FOLIO_FORMATO,BIMESTRE,REMESA,ANIO  from becarios";
            var data=cnx.GetData(sql);
            gdtgvDetallesS3db.DataSource = data;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
       
    }
```

Seccion de la conexion para el archivo s3db:

public SQLiteConnection GetConnection(string ruta)

```
    {  cad_sqlite = @"Data Source="+ruta;
        try
        {
             sqlitecnn = new SQLiteConnection(cad_sqlite);
            sqlitecnn.Open();
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            throw new SQLiteException("Error: Al conectarse a la Base de datos." + ex.Message);
        }
        

        return null;
    }
```

SECCION de BOTON de INSERTAR de la capa de la vista:

private void gBtnBuscarDB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
        Becarios dtBecarios = new Becarios();
        ModeloBecarios smBecarios = new ModeloBecarios();
        try
        {
            //cnxmysql = new ConexionBD();

            for(int i= 0; i < gdtgvDetallesS3db.RowCount; i++)
            {
                dtBecarios.Id_programa = Convert.ToInt32(gdtgvDetallesS3db.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                dtBecarios.Nombre = gdtgvDetallesS3db.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                dtBecarios.Primer_apellido = gdtgvDetallesS3db.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                dtBecarios.Segundo_apellido = gdtgvDetallesS3db.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                dtBecarios.Curp = gdtgvDetallesS3db.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                dtBecarios.Telefono = gdtgvDetallesS3db.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                dtBecarios.Email = gdtgvDetallesS3db.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
                dtBecarios.Grado_escolar = Convert.ToInt32(gdtgvDetallesS3db.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value.ToString());
                dtBecarios.Region_id = gdtgvDetallesS3db.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
                dtBecarios.Sede = gdtgvDetallesS3db.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value.ToString();
                dtBecarios.Cve_cct = gdtgvDetallesS3db.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value.ToString();
                dtBecarios.Nombre_cct = gdtgvDetallesS3db.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value.ToString();
                dtBecarios.Cct=gdtgvDetallesS3db.Rows[i].Cells[12].Value.ToString();
                dtBecarios.Municipio_id = Convert.ToInt32(gdtgvDetallesS3db.Rows[i].Cells[13].Value.ToString());
                dtBecarios.Cve_localidad = Convert.ToInt32(gdtgvDetallesS3db.Rows[i].Cells[14].Value.ToString());
                dtBecarios.Localidad_id = Convert.ToInt32(gdtgvDetallesS3db.Rows[i].Cells[15].Value.ToString());
                dtBecarios.Folio_formato = gdtgvDetallesS3db.Rows[i].Cells[16].Value.ToString();
                dtBecarios.Bimestre = Convert.ToInt32(gdtgvDetallesS3db.Rows[i].Cells[17].Value.ToString());
                dtBecarios.Remesa = gdtgvDetallesS3db.Rows[i].Cells[18].Value.ToString();
                dtBecarios.Anio = gdtgvDetallesS3db.Rows[i].Cells[19].Value.ToString();
                smBecarios.SetBecarios(dtBecarios);

            }
            
        }
        
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        
    }
```

SECCION del METODO para INSERTAR en mi CAPA de MODELO:

public bool SetBecarios(Becarios dtBecarios)

```
    {
        string Query = string.Format("INSERT INTO becarios (ID_PROGRAMA,NOMBRE,PRIMER_APELLIDO,SEGUNDO_APELLIDO," +
                                     "CURP,TELEFONO,EMAIL,GRADO_ESCOLAR,REGION_ID,SEDE,CVE_CCT,NOMBRE_CCT,CCT," +
                                     "MUNICIPIO_ID,CVE_LOCALIDAD,LOCALIDAD_ID,FOLIO_FORMATO,BIMESTRE,REMESA,ANIO) " +
                                     "VALUES({0},'{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}',{7},'{8}','{9}','{10}','{11}'," +
                                     "'{12}',{13},{14},{15},'{16}',{17},'{18}','{19}')",
                                    dtBecarios.Id_programa, dtBecarios.Nombre, dtBecarios.Primer_apellido, dtBecarios.Segundo_apellido,
                                    dtBecarios.Curp, dtBecarios.Telefono, dtBecarios.Email, dtBecarios.Grado_escolar,
                                    dtBecarios.Region_id, dtBecarios.Sede, dtBecarios.Cve_cct, dtBecarios.Nombre_cct,
                                    dtBecarios.Cct, dtBecarios.Municipio_id, dtBecarios.Cve_localidad, dtBecarios.Localidad_id,
                                    dtBecarios.Folio_formato, dtBecarios.Bimestre, dtBecarios.Remesa, dtBecarios.Anio);
        try
        {
            int result = ExecuteQuery(Query);
                 if (result > 0)
                    return true;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }


        return false;
    }
```

Espero Alguien me pueda ayudar por favor.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! En que momento tira el error? al hacer el insert?

Answer (score 0):

Sería de gran ayuda que nos mostraras cómo estás invocando SetBecarios.

Hasta donde puedo ver, estás creando una conexión por cada vez que llamas el método y no cierras la conexión.

El pool que tienes configurado en tu servidor ha de ser 50. Es por eso que al abrir la conexión 51 ya no puede conectarse porque las anteriores 50 quedaron abiertas.

Te sugiero que reutilices la conexión para todos los insert, y no hagas de uno en uno. Puedes insertar por bloques mayores para agilizar el proceso.

Espero sea de ayuda.